# Understanding Vout

Tags: transactions

I have searched around for this and found the following article [In getrawtransaction, what is the vout integer in the vin list?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/in-getrawtransaction-what-is-the-vout-integer-in-the-vin-list). However I am a very visual learner and this does not make much sense mostly because the two transactions I tested don't seem to follow the rule in the post or more likely I don't get it.

For transaction [`1d7f54deccb7b2646a4ba83c6884dbac953b0588c8943d0e7e8f7c8f559d5d72`](https://blockchain.info/tx/1d7f54deccb7b2646a4ba83c6884dbac953b0588c8943d0e7e8f7c8f559d5d72) I expect the `vout` to be 1 which is correct and I validated through use of `gettxid`.

However for transaction [`ef96555197df4397ac4fed180903ce760fe8b59b85da83baba5ecd2a0fac7ec1`](https://blockchain.info/tx/ef96555197df4397ac4fed180903ce760fe8b59b85da83baba5ecd2a0fac7ec1) I expect the `vout` to be 2 which is not correct per validation with `gettxid`. The correct number is in fact 0.

Can anyone explain this to me why `vout` for the second transaction would be 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VOUT is the index of the output within the transaction that the input is spending.  The first output in a transaction is index 0, the second is index 1, etc.  The transaction you referenced has two outputs, so it has outputs 0 and 1.  You would reference txid:0 to spend the first output and txid:1 to spend the second output.

Comment: Thank you that makes a ton of sense don't know why I was having trouble with it!