# getrawtransaction method in details

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, api, json-rpc

Referring to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions,
I`m using getrawtrasaction method call to define as much information about incoming payment transaction details as possibe. Is there any detailed information about fields that are returned by getrawtransaction method? 
For example what means "vout" field? How can be useful "scriptSig" field that consists of "asm" and "hex"?

Comment: related: [In getrawtransaction, what is the vout integer in the vin list?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/in-getrawtransaction-what-is-the-vout-integer-in-the-vin-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bitcoin transaction takes a number of inputs and spends those input to the specified outputs. If the value of inputs exceeds outputs the network treats that as a miner's fee.

vout is the list of output transactions.

scriptSig is only useful if you're trying to do some non-standard stuff.

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions for more information on what's in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, check out this excellent [post](http://grantammons.me/2014/01/17/bitcoin-litecoin-dogecoin-exploring-the-block-chain/).